# Customize asterisk color of the label in the required TextField on variant default, focused, and filled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am able to change the color of asterisk by `createTheme` in the default state.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  MuiFormLabel: {
    styleOverrides: {
      asterisk: {
        color: '#E54D39',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

TextField - default variant

[image: TextField default variant]

But the asterisk color should be blue like the label and not red when the TextField is focused or filled. But I don't know how to customize in `createTheme` because `Mui-focused` is not inside the same element as `MuiFormLabel-asterisk`.

TextField - focused variant

[image: TextField focused variant]

[image: TextField focused in dev tools]

```
MuiFormLabel: {
  styleOverrides: {
    // This is not working
    // root: {
    //  '&.MuiFormLabel-focused': {
    //    asterisk: {
    //      color: '#E54D39',
    //    },
    //  },
    // },
    asterisk: {
      color: '#E54D39',
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MUI docs **[Overrides based on props](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#overrides-based-on-props)**:

> You can pass a callback as a value in each slot of the component's
> `styleOverrides` to apply styles based on props.
>
> The `ownerState` prop is a combination of public props that you pass
> to the component + internal state of the component.

As a part of `ownersState` for `MuiFormLabel`, you can get the `focused` and `filled` states which will give you what you're looking for.  For example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        asterisk: ({ ownerState }) => ({
          color: ownerState.focused || ownerState.filled ? "inherit" : "#E54D39"
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Which produces:

[image: example fields]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-asterisk-with-ownerstate-js-7wghtl?file=/src/Demo.js:186-428